# How to not active a select function to all selects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I'm working on a page where I have multiple selects.

For one of them (let's call it "select-1") I have a function which is hiding/showing a content div,
and inside this content div I also have a select (let's call it "select-2").

So my problem is that when I use this "select-2" it triggers my function.

I'm searching a way to trigger this function only for the "select-1"
I've tried many stuffs but im not very skilled in Jquery so it's not working.

Here is the function :

```
function func(select){
      $(select).find("option:selected").each(function(){
          var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
          if(optionValue){
              $(".list").not("." + optionValue).hide();
              $("." + optionValue).show();
              $(".targetDiv").not("." + optionValue).hide();
              $("." + optionValue).show();
          } else{
              $(".list").hide();
          }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Please include all relevant html code

Comment: How are you calling `func`?

Comment: Also, assuming that it's `<select id="select-1">`, simply use `$("#select-1")` to refer to it and only it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following html won't match yours since you haven't shown any but the concept will be easy to adapt to yours.

For  a `multiple` select, jQuery `val()` returns an array of all the values selected.

Using a data attribute on the content elements and `filter()` we can first hide all items then filter the ones that are in the value array to show

```js
// only target select-1 with event listener
$('#select-1').change(function() {
  const valArray = $(this).val();
  const $list = $('.list').hide(); // hide whole collection

  if (valArray.length) {
    // when options selected filter the ones to show
    $list.filter(function() {
      return valArray.includes($(this).data('item'));
    }).show()
  }
});
```

```css
.list{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select 1
<select id="select-1" multiple size="5">

  <option value="">Select item</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
<h3>
  List
</h3>
<ul>
  <li class="list" data-item="one">One</li>
  <li class="list" data-item="two">Two</li>
  <li class="list" data-item="three">Three</li>
  <li class="list" data-item="four">Four</li>
</ul>
```